# unknown number of files in \input command

Tags: input

i need to load unknown number of "`files.tex`" in a folder and run LaTeX with `\input` command.
i am trying the code below:

```
\bash[stdout]<br>
find . -type f | wc -l
\END
```

and run `\input{file.tex}` unknown number of times.

Comment: In random order? In a real life it is not indifferent, when you put  on pants and underwear.

Answer (score 3):

A pipe can be used with the shell escape feature (Option `-shell-escape` in TeX Live or `--enable-pipes`/`--enable-write18` in MiKTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newread\mypipe
\begin{document}

% Open a pipe and read the files line by line.
% Line ends are disabled by \endlinechar=-1
\begingroup
  \openin\mypipe="|find . -name \string\*.tex"
  \endlinechar=-1
  \xdef\FileList{}
  \let\do\relax
  \makeatletter
  \@whilesw\unless\ifeof\mypipe\fi{%
    \read\mypipe to \x
    \xdef\FileList{\FileList\do{\x}}%
  }    
\endgroup
% The file list is now in macro `\FileList`, each file name
% as argument to `\do`.

\def\do#1{%
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\par
  % \input{#1}%
}
\FileList
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `\globinput` macro that takes as optional argument a path (default `.` representing the working directory) and as mandatory argument a string to be passed onto `find` for searching files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\globinput}{O{.}m}
 {
  \alexandre_globinput:fn { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } } { #1 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_alexandre_globinput_stream

\cs_new_protected:Nn \alexandre_globinput:nn
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_alexandre_globinput_stream
   {% the pipe
    "|find~#2~-name~#1"
   }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_alexandre_globinput_stream
   {
    \input{##1}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \alexandre_globinput:nn { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\globinput[tmp]{\*.tex}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output of `ls -R` in order to show the setup:

```
> ls -R
alexandre.aux   alexandre.log   alexandre.pdf   alexandre.tex   tmp/

./tmp:
a.tex   b.tex   c.txt   d.tex
```

Running LaTeX on the document with `-shell-escape` enabled will input `a.tex`, `b.tex` and `d.tex`. Indeed, this is what is shown in the console.

```
> pdflatex -shell-escape alexandre.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./alexandre.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def)))
No file alexandre.aux.
(./tmp/a.tex) (./tmp/b.tex) (./tmp/d.tex) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/
fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./alexandre.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/201
6/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on alexandre.pdf (1 page, 10280 bytes).
Transcript written on alexandre.log.
```

Note that if you run on the current directory (no path argument), you'll also input the main file, which is not really desirable. A test might be added in the map to exclude `\jobname.tex`.